# Pickle module in Java

Tags: java, python

I made this method in Python :

```
def save(a, b, c):
    if not os.path.exists("./Data"): 
        os.makedirs("./Data")
    else:
        pass
    var_save = {1: a, 2: b, 3: c }
    savefile = open('./save.txt','wb')
    pickle.dump(var_save, savefile)
    savefile.close()
```

Now I would like to migrate it to a Java program, but it looks like there's no Pickle module in Java. Does anyone know a way of doing this in Java? (a, b and c are Integers)

Comment: Java uses something called the `Serializable` interface.

Comment: I think you would be better served with JSON or XML, but if you need specifically pickle, this repo exists: https://github.com/irmen/pickle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should investigate [Java serialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/serial.html)

> To serialize an object means to convert its state to a byte stream so
>   that the byte stream can be reverted back into a copy of the object. A
>   Java object is serializable if its class or any of its superclasses
>   implements either the java.io.Serializable interface or its
>   subinterface, java.io.Externalizable. Deserialization is the process
>   of converting the serialized form of an object back into a copy of the
>   object.

Java can serialize natively to a byte stream. That bytestream can be a file, a network stream etc. Additionally a number of 3rd party libraries exist to serialise to [XML](http://xstream.codehaus.org/), [JSON](https://code.google.com/p/json-io/) etc.

Comment: But can't you only serialize an object ?

Comment: In the above you appear to have a list (of integers). That would appear to me to be an object

Comment: Also, in Java, the Integer class is Serializable.

Comment: Can I take a conclusion that we can't serialize an arbitrary object? So we are limited to objects whose class implements the Serializable interface?