# Is there a similar alternative to Python's pickle module for Java?

Tags: java

Basically, I'm looking for a way to save a variable to a file, and load it with ease. I've tried things such as XML, but it doesn't seem to be what I need. I'm trying to save a Boolean, such as a setting, to a file, and not make the user change them every time they open the program.

Comment: Can you please check whether this answer helps ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23545749/pickle-module-in-java

Comment: Java has whole APIs for this use case. See [Preferences](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html), [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) and maybe [ResourceBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)